# Scroll DIV only with overflow-y

Tags: html, css

How to scroll the div only when focused not the whole page.

I have a widget that has an overflow-y: auto, wherein when it is expanded, a scroll bar will appear, but the problem is it will not scroll when using the mouse wheel.

With the mouse wheel, the whole page will only scroll

I want that when the widget is focused, scrolling with the mouse wheel should work

[Div Sroll this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4flOP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you should add `tabindex` attribute.

ex:

```
<div tabindex="1"></div>
```

by adding tabindex your element will be focused and can be scrolled.

more info [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)